# Удаленный доступ к MySQL на MariaDB

Tags: mysql, база-данных, ip, vps, mariadb

Сайт находиться на VPS, база очень большая 1гб, развернули MySQL MariaDB на терминальном сервере, как теперь законектить БД с сайтом?

Сеть для подключения имеет один IP. Я так понимаю, что нужно вместо localhost указать - IP:3306, но конекта нет. Читал, что можно открыть MySQL в интернет для определенного IP, но как это сделать инструкции нет.

Как подключить, чтобы MySQL с сайтом связалась?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89644/discussion-on-question-by-evgenich----mysql--mariadb).

Answer (score 0):

Решение вышло такое: - нужно сделать проброс портов на роутере (аналогично как с rdp), а также закомментировать или удалить строчку `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` в настройках MariaDB.

Comment: Странно, эта строчка вроде наоборот нужная